# EF multiplicity constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, tags, constraints

[image]

With code first approach how can I set up this scenario ?

"Each person could have 1 or 0 car, every car have 0 to 3 owners".

Do I need to add a constraint or is there a tag that could help me ?

Comment: You could have a junction table having PersonId, CarId and a third column in it that can only have values 0..2. These three columns should be in a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a tag and also, on relational databases, there is not a constraint (you can write a trigger).

If the multiplicity is only 3 you could have 3 different properties on Person. In this case you can still have a non mapped property to access to the 3 properties using Car[].